# Shuffling combinations without converting iterable (itertools.combinations) to list

Tags: python, combinations, shuffle, python-itertools

The following simple code gives me the possible combinations of length 3 of 200 elements.

```
from itertools import combinations
comb = combinations( range(200), 3 )
```

I want to get the combinations in a random order in order to pick the first N combinations. However, if I convert comb to a list and shuffle it as following, I may get a memory error because the list might contain too many elements:

```
comb = list(comb) # This might be huge and give a memory error 
random.shuffle(comb)
N = 10
comb = comb[:10] # get only the first N random combinations
```

Is there any other way to get N random combinations ? (i.e., not in the order generated by itertools.combinations).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are `C(200, 3) = 1313400` possible combinations. As you also mentioned, this number can easily get out of hand due to the [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion). For example, if you choose 4 instead of 3 elements, the number of combinations will be approximately 50 times larger (64684950). Instead of randomly selecting from these combinations, you can randomly build possible combinations.

To build those combinations, you can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) from the random library. `random.sample(range(200), 3)` will randomly generate one of those 1313400 combinations. If you call it again, it will generate another combination.

There are two issues:

1. Order is important in `random.sample` ([1, 2, 3] is different than [1, 3, 2]). In combinations, it is not. To solve that, you can use `sorted()`.
2. `random.sample` will independently generate the next 3 numbers. Therefore, the combinations generated in different iterations could be the same. Although it is very unlikely for this example (≈0.0000343), you can use a set to store the combinations so that only unique combinations will be stored.

The following will generate 10 different combinations:

```
import random
combs = set()
N = 10
while len(combs) < N:
    combs.add(tuple(sorted(random.sample(range(200), 3))))
```

Comment: This answer doesn't take advantage of the properties of iterators

Comment: @mprat I don't think iterators have any adventages in this case. In your function below, you are assigning `pool = tuple(iterable)`. If you call the function with `random_combination(comb, 10)` that will generate all possible combinations and store them in a variable called pool. This is exactly what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: @mprat: This fundamentally isn't a stream operation; iterators have no advantages. Even your answer, taken from the `itertools` documentation, makes zero use of `itertools` or iterator operations; it's only listed in the `itertools` docs because it's a related task to `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: @ayhan: You may be ragging too hard on itertools. The `random_combination` function in the itertools docs isn't intended to be used the way mprat used it. The idea is that you'd call it on `range(200)`, not `comb`, and it would give you a single random combination without materializing all combinations; the `pool` would only materialize `range(200)`.

Comment: @user2357112 I couldn't be sure about that because then the function is basically the same as `random.sample`. The only difference is that it selects indices instead of elements but that shouldn't change much.

Comment: @ayhan: It pretty nearly is the same! The only differences are whether the output is a tuple or a list, and that `random.sample` returns random elements in a random *order*; `random_combination` always returns elements in the order they appeared in the input, like `itertools.combinations`.