# How to sample without duplication in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I want to sample 30 samples in a `list` with length 100.

I can use np.random.sample like this:

```
import numpy as np
l = list(range(100))
np.random.choice(l, 30)
# np.random.choice(l, 30) may be same with next time np.random.choice(l, 30)
```

This can get a sample group, but I need to sample several times.

For example, I need 3 sublist(length=3) from a list with length 10(just a demo).

the duplicated samples is meaningless for me. which means [1,2,3] and [3,2,1] is duplicated for me. but `np.random.choice` may produce there two for me.

Is there any methods in python that can help me? Or is there a way I can compare the sampled list faster?

Comment: how is the memory cost of `combination` too high? it's a generator...

Comment: How many times do you need to sample? If you want to sample multiple times without duplication, then you need to remember what you've sampled. Sampling just once is the most effective way so try to reconsider that requirement and redesign your code.

Comment: @Tranbi combinations is a generator, but i need to random.sample it, which means i need to make it list, generator cant be sampled, i think?

Comment: If you have only 100 numbers and you are consuming 30 per sample, if you sample more than 3 times you will have consumed all of them (since order does not matter for you). I did not understand what you mean by "sample several times (may be very large, like 10000)".

Comment: Got it. have you checked the following already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779729/shuffling-combinations-without-converting-iterable-itertools-combinations-to-l

Comment: @nonDucor  for example, sample([1,2,3], 2) may get [1,2] and [1,3], i need to check these two list one by one. one of difference in my sample will make huge difference in my experiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list has only 100 elements, you can `random.shuffle` it and get the first 30 elements.

```py
import random

l = list(range(100))
random.shuffle(l)
print(l[:30])
```

Comment: good idea, but i think it will produce duplicated samples? as shuffle may be same.

Comment: @nick, it will not if the original list does not have duplicated elements (if it does, convert it to a set and them back to a list to get rid of them). Note that I'm not shuffling and getting the first element, them shuffling again. You shuffle once and get the first 30 elements of the shuffled list.

Comment: @nick Yes, if you want to do this multiple times then it'll have duplicates. But how many times do you want to sample and how many elements do you want for each sample? Please specify it in the question.

Comment: this sample operation i need to do many times, about duplication, i mean, the first 30 samples may be same with the samples i sampled later

Comment: @TedKleinBergman thanks, i will add the information

Comment: @nick So you do allow duplicates of subsequent samples? Then this answer and you're `np.random.sample(l, 30)` will work fine. I think you need to clarify more what you want and show a practical example.